# How do I build perception_pcl from source?

Tags: ros, pcl, build, ros-fuerte, perception-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get some version of perception_pcl that compiles under ros 1.8.9 (fuerte)
perception_pcl in order to satisfy the final dependency for the velodyne stack. The trouble is that the roslocate info perception_pcl gives me a bogus URI:

```
http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_unstable
```

Of course I've been able to find tags that are valid references, but those I've selected fail with obscure gcc errors. What would make sense to me is to pull version 1.2.3 of perception_pcl, since that's the version that's listed when you run

```
apt-cache showpkg ros-fuerte-perception-pcl
```

I would list the compile errors I saw, but I think it's irrelevant. Someone responsible for the fuerte release should know how the perception_pcl package was built.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45555/how-do-i-build-perception_pcl-from-source?/) by [Bryce Hathaway](https://answers.ros.org/users/3344/bryce-hathaway/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can define which ROS distribution to target on roslocate:

```
roslocate info --distro=fuerte perception_pcl
```

This will point you to the correct version of perception_pcl for fuerte:

```
- svn:
    local-name: perception_pcl
    uri: http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/tags/perception_pcl_fuerte-1.2.3
```

Remember to run *rosmake perception_pcl* with the option *--rosdep-install*, so any dependencies can be installed before attempting to compile the package.

If this doesn't solve your issue, more information about your OS, ROS version and errors would allow us to provide you a better answer.

---

Originally posted by [flamenco](https://answers.ros.org/users/944/flamenco/) with karma: 40 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bryce Hathaway](https://answers.ros.org/users/3344/bryce-hathaway/) on 2012-10-15**:
This sounds great, but didn't work for me. First, while I get the same result running the roslocate commnd, the tag doesn't exist. The closest tag is perception_pcl_unstable-1.2.3. Secondly, it doesn't seem like rosmake has a --rosdep-install option.